# mouseover event to control fadeto

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseenter, fadeto

I'm trying to cause an image to fadeTo to a particular opacity but triggered when the mouseover (mouseenter, mouseleave) is on the parent div.

The code below shows two div elements (working fine) but for some reason it doesn't work when i change ".children("div")" to ".children("img")" given that I actually have an image in there of course.

Is there some syntax or naming convention I'm missing?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(".title").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).children("img").fadeTo("fast", 0.8);
  });
  $(".title").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo("fast", 1.0);


  });
  
});
```

```css
.wrap {
 width: auto;
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-right: 2%;
 padding-left: 2%;
 padding-right: 2%;
 float: none;
}
.title {
 border: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
    background: #000;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition-property: all;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;
 transition-timing-function: ease;
 transition-delay: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 40px;
}
img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<div class="fluid wrap" ontouchstart="">
            <div class="title">
            <img src="https://inkplant.com/images/code/red-box.jpg"/>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: and where is the <img> in your html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention where the image is, but I think you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".title").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find("img").fadeTo("fast", 0.8);
        });
  $(".title").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find("img").fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
  });
});
```

This is because

```
.children
```

only affects direct descendants of your target element.

```
.find
```

will find any element that is a child of the target node

Comment: awesome cheers. the .children actually started working. maybe i made a typo in the markup somewhere. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error with `</div>` after your `<img>` its a wrong typo I think

if your img with class box use

```
$(this).find(".box")
```

instead of

```
$(this).children("div")
```

if your img not have any class just use

```
 $(this).find("img")
```

Comment: thanks a lot. the "img" is now working. must have made a mistake in my markup or something. cheers!